# How do I access my host's network stats in my Prometheus Node Exporter Docker Container?

Tags: docker, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I want to monitor my recieved and transmitted packages in Prometheus and used the Node Exporter for this. I've followed tutorials which highlighted the need to mount `/proc` and `/sys` as read-only in a seperate folder.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--collector.filesystem.mount-points-exclude=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)'
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    networks:
      - proxy
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

The exports of the fs size, CPU and memory look plausible, but the network statistics look wrong:

[image: The network statistics are a constant line at about 20kbps]

When I look at `/proc/net/netstat` in my host, it looks quite different than both `/host/proc/net/netstat` and `/rootfs/proc/net/netstat` in my container (which are actually both identical to `/proc/net/netstat` in the container). So the stats I'm seeing are probably from the container itself.

I checked my `/proc` folder on my host and saw that the `net` directory is a link to `self/net`, which is another link itself. Could that be an issue?
And if not, what do I need to do to access my host's network stats?

Comment: Does this Github issue [here](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/1697) answer your question?